# Multiple appendices, distributed throughout document

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, numbering, chapters, appendices

For my dissertation, I have multiple `parts` to represent each separate paper. I'm trying to get the `appendix` for each `part` to follow the `part`, and then have chapter numbering reset to 1 (rather than continuing in the appendix style as A, B, C, etc.).

The code I'm currently using, which isn't working:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Part I}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\chapter{Chapter 2}

\begin{appendix}

\chapter{Appendix 1}

\chapter{Appendix 2}

\end{appendix}

\part{Part II}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\chapter{Chapter 2}

\begin{appendix}

\chapter{Appendix 1}

\end{appendix}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the environment `appendices` provided by the package [`appendix`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/appendix).

Replace `\begin{appendix} ... \end{appendix}` with `\begin{appendices} ... \end{appendices}` and add the following lines in your preamble

```
\makeatletter
  \@addtoreset{chapter}{part}
  \@addtoreset{@ppsaveapp}{part}
\makeatother
```

to reset chapter numbering (counter `chapter`) and appendix numbering (counter `@ppsaveapp`) each time a `part` starts.

Thus your modified code

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{appendix}

\makeatletter
  \@addtoreset{chapter}{part}
  \@addtoreset{@ppsaveapp}{part}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Part I}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\chapter{Chapter 2}

\begin{appendices}

\chapter{Appendix 1}

\chapter{Appendix 2}

\end{appendices}

\part{Part II}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\chapter{Chapter 2}

\begin{appendices}

\chapter{Appendix 1}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

will output

[image]

Answer (score 5):

rather than use `\begin{appendix} ... \end{appendix}`, i'd be inclined to create
a command `\restartchapters` and use that similarly to the way `\appendix` is used.

a possible definition would be parallel to the present definition of `\appendix`:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\restartchapters{\par
  \setcounter{chapter}{0}%
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \gdef\@chapapp{\chaptername}%
  \gdef\thechapter{\@arabic\c@chapter}}
\makeatother
```

then i'd invoke `\restartchapters` immediately after every `\part` line.
you should be able to alternate `\appendix` and `\restartchapters` ad infinitum.

you could also modify the `\@endpart` definition from `book.cls`, but the
suggested definition is less invasive, and since `\part` is otherwise a nice
clean break point, it's probably safer unless you're really familiar with
tinkering in the innards of a class file.

if you have cross-part cross-references, you should probably reset `\thechapter` to
include the part number, as  `\gdef\thechapter{\thepart.\@arabic\c@chapter}` in
the definition above.

(this hasn't been tested, but if i had to do this, it's what i'd start with.)