# Display of Appendix titles in TOC and in the Document

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, numbering, chapters, appendices

[image]

The code below produces the contents page and appendix labels shown.
I would like the First line Appendixes to appear without a numnber.
I would then like to have appendix 1 labelled A1 and appendix 2 A2.

A similar question was asked here:

[Multiple appendices, distributed throughout document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129082/multiple-appendices-distributed-throughout-document)

but I have tried using the package appendix but it doesn't make any difference?

```
\documentclass{report}
%\usepackage{appendix}


%\makeatletter
%  \@addtoreset{chapter}{part}
%  \@addtoreset{@ppsaveapp}{part}
%\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
%\begin{appendices}
\section{Appendices}
\subsection{appendix 1}
\subsection{appendix 2}
%\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Should the appendices really be `\subsection`s? In `book` or `report`, appendices normally are `\chapter`s.

Comment: I guess they can be a chapter if that helps

Comment: Bazman: It's not a TeX technical issue, but rather a typographical aspect.

Answer (score 3):

Just a proposition -- there is no general rule on appendices, so it's sometimes a *make an educated guess* what is desired/requested.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}%
\usepackage{blindtext}

\addtolength{\cftchapnumwidth}{10pt}%
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Dummy}
\blindtext

\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\chapter*{Appendices}

\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Appendices}%
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{A\arabic{chapter}}
\chapter{Super Appendix 1}%
\chapter{Super Appendix 2}%
\end{document}
```

[image]